# sed without regex

Tags: file-management, sed, find-and-replace, gnu, gnuwin32

I am using GNU SED for find and replace functionality on large files(upto 2GB).

Find and replace characters can contain any characters, hence I want find and replace parameters to be treated as plain text as it comes.

I do not want to treat either find or replace parameters as regex by sed command.

I have experimented a lot, but every time I am getting new combinations of regex which does not work for sed as plain text.

How can this be achieved?

Is there any formula to escape the special characters?

Note:  I am using `~` operator as command seperator instead of `/`

Below is the example

```
sed -ne "s~^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$~Replace" -ne "w output.txt" "input.txt"
```

Above command does not work, as it treats the find parameter as regex(as it is regex).
Hence to find the text I have to escape some special characters in regex as below

```
sed -ne "s~\^\[-+\]?\[0-9\]\*\\.?\[0-9\]+(\[eE\]\[-+\]?\[0-9\]+)?\$~Replace" -ne "w output.txt" "input.txt"
```

In another example I have to modify `.*$` to `.\*\$`
But in `(.*$)` 
I do not want to mofify input.

So is there any universal rule for escape sequence?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Sample input and expected output for example.

Comment: Use single-quotes instead of double-quotes, then the shell will leave those characters alone.

Comment: but it throws following error sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Comment: You're missing a terminating `~`. Which version of sed is this?

Comment: sed -ne 's~a.d~sss~g' -ne 'w output.txt' 'input.txt' This is my command, which is giving the error. And sed version is => GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: That command works here.

Comment: @Thor It's not working on my command prompt. Can sed verison be an issue?

Comment: I have the same version. Try re-typing the command.

Comment: sadly, it's not working:-(

Comment: I agree with @Thor on two points: (1) That `sed -ne 's~a.d~sss~g' -ne 'w output.txt' 'input.txt'` command looks perfectly valid, and it works on my system.  (2) You need to explain your problem better.  You say you want a “universal rule” right after saying that you want some characters to represent themselves literally while others implement their regex functionality.

Comment: I just do not want regex behavior of sed command. I want all the arguments supplied to sed for find and replace, to be treated as plain text irrespective of anything

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your replies! My problem got solved. I am running above sed version on windws 7. I have used below syntax of sed. sed -nre "s~a\.d~sss~g;w output.txt" "input.txt". Since I have used -r as the option, I am escaping all special characters which are being used in regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q:** Is there any formula to escape the special characters?
>   **Q:** Is there any universal rule for escape sequence?

**A:** You can use the corresponding hex code for special characters, in cases where just typing `/`,`.`,`*`,`?`,`$`, etc. becomes annoying. For example:

```
sed -rn '/\x22/p' file
```

will print lines that contain double quotes, since `\x22` represents `"`.

If you need to look up hex codes, you can conveniently save them all to a file with this command:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<255;i++){printf("%d\t%x\t%c\n", i,i,i)}}' null >chars.txt
```

Comment: This seems to directly answer the two clear questions that the OP is asking.